# How to load geojson file from hard drive with Loadgeojson

Tags: javascript

I've recently discovered google Maps api javascript and I'm discovering html too. I've started with the tutorials and it works quite Well but I'm trying To use loadgeojson with a local file and it doesn't work. I'm sure I'm doing wrong. When I use this code in my html file :

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json');
    }
```

It works, but I've downloaded the file google.json on my  hard drive in c:\documents\maps and tried this:

```
  map.data.loadGeoJson('C:/documents/maps/google.json');
    }
```

But nothing happens...

Comment: You need to run a localhost server and load file from a web path. Lots of ways to set up localhost on your computer

Comment: Pit inside your project and refer to it relatively

Comment: Thanks for your answer charlietfl. I thought it wasn't necessary to create a localhost. So I'll do so. What do you mean abderrahmane ? you know I'm really a beginner so I'm not sure To understand. Do you have an example ?

Comment: Try `file:///C:/documents/maps/google.json`

Comment: Thanks Deckerz, I've tried that :  map.data.loadGeoJson('file:///C:/documents/maps/google.json');
    }  but without success

Comment: Well, I've install a localhost and it works fine. Thank you